# why does openfiledialog cause excel to be added to task manager processes?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

why does this cause an occurrence of excel to be open?

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            //EXCEL.EXE *32 is now showing in the task manager!
```

i am choosing an `XLSX` file from the `openfiledialog` and as shown above i am seeing the process in the task manager.

can someone please tell me how is this possible?

Comment: If all else fails, single-step thru the code!  It should quickly show which line causes the issue.   Also, any objects returned by Excel must also be released via ReleaseComObject when finished, eg. xlWorkBook, xlWorkSheet, xlWorkSheet.get_Range, EmailList.Cells.  Miss one any Excel will stay open.

Comment: ps. As an aside, your cleanup code should be in a finally block, to guarantee it gets called regardless of success or exception.

Comment: thanks so much will. can you please see edited question i think i found the reason why

Comment: This happens because of shell extensions you have installed on your machine.  They'll load into your process when you use OpenFileDialog.  You probably have one that uses Excel to display "rich information" on Excel spreadsheet files.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to disable them one by one if you have no clue which one might do it.

Comment: @HansPassant wow thanks so much for this info. how do i get into sysinternals?

Answer (score 1):

If Excel is already open, you should try to get this instance, instead of creating a new one.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

Excel.Application xl = null; 
try {
    // Try to get an existing instance
    xl = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
} catch (COMException ex) { 
    // Excel was not open. Open a new instance
    xl = new Excel.ApplicationClass(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help. my application opens excel and it should close it. what do you mean by "excel already open?"

Comment: There might be an Excel application open already - either visible or unvisible. In the latter case you would see it in the task manager.

Comment: Go through the code step by step in the debugger. May be it will give you a hint where the second instance opens ...

Comment: thank you! i did exactly what yo usaid and i am seeing interesitng behavior. please look at my edited quesiton